# Table without content in Chrome

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to display a table with its contents in Chrome. However, I can only do this in Firefox and Opera (the browsers I have tested so far). The funny thing is that the textContent of the td elements are set for all the browsers mentioned:

```
<table id="total" style="width:300px;margin-top:20px;">
 <tr>
   <td></td> 
   <td></td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td> 
   <td></td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td> 
   <td></td> 
 </tr>
</table> 

configText: function(elem, msg)
{
    "use strict";
    if (typeof elem === "undefined")
    {
        throw new Error("elem does not exist");
    }
    else if (elem.nodeType !== 1)
    {
        throw new Error("elem is not a valid element");
    }
    else if (typeof msg !== "string")
    {
        throw new Error("msg is not a string");
    }
    else {
        if ("textContent" in elem)
        {
            delete elem.textContent;
            elem.textContent = msg;
        }
        else if ("innerText" in elem)
        {
            delete elem.textContent;
            elem.innerText = msg;
        }
    }
 }


function createTotalTable(arrayTotal, arrayMsg)
{
"use strict";

var td;
var arrayCounter = 0;
var table = document.createElement("table");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        if (j % 2 === 0)
        {
            U.configText(td, arrayMsg[arrayCounter]);
            arrayCounter++;
        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    try {
        U.configText(td, arrayTotal[i]);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.log("Error: " + err.name + " on file " +
                err.fileName + " at line number " + err.lineNumber + " with message " + err.message);
    }

    table.id = "total";
    table.appendChild(tr);
    table.style.width = "300px";
    table.style.marginTop = "20px";
}

// elem.parentNode.insertBefore(table, elem.nextSibling);
$(table).insertAfter($("#graphics"));
}
```

Comment: why can't you step through the code in the debugger to find the error?

Comment: The last line and the tagging of the question really doesn't make much sense, if you're using jQuery, why are you doing it this way at all, and not using the cross browser text() method ?

Comment: so in which browser it does not work then?